# Does public static AutocompleteSessionToken newInstance () return same instance?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Does this method behave on singleton pattern? or does it create new session for the user each time?

the below method is called on edittext change listener.

```
   @NonNull
   private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(@NonNull CharSequence constraint) {

       final ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

       // Create a new token for the autocomplete session. Pass this to FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest,
       // and once again when the user makes a selection (for example when calling fetchPlace()).
       AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

       //https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540
       // Use the builder to create a FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.
       FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
              .setLocationBias(bounds)
               .setCountry("PK")
               .setSessionToken(token)
               .setQuery(constraint.toString())
               .build();

       Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> autocompletePredictions = placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request);

       // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most
       // 60s for a result from the API.
       try {
           Tasks.await(autocompletePredictions, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       } catch (@NonNull ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       if (autocompletePredictions.isSuccessful()) {
           FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse findAutocompletePredictionsResponse = autocompletePredictions.getResult();
           if (findAutocompletePredictionsResponse != null)
               for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : findAutocompletePredictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
                   Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPlaceId());
                   resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(), prediction.getPrimaryText(STYLE_NORMAL).toString(), prediction.getFullText(STYLE_BOLD).toString()));
               }

           return resultList;
       } else {
           return resultList;
       }

   }
```

the method calls on each text change in editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()` method returns a new instance, i.e. a new session token. Each time you call this method, you are [creating](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/session-tokens#create-session-tokens) a new session token.

Google explains how autocomplete sessions work [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#session_tokens):

> Session tokens group the query and selection phases of a user
>   autocomplete search into a discrete session for billing purposes. The
>   session begins when the user starts typing a query, and concludes when
>   they select a place. Each session can have multiple queries, followed
>   by one place selection. Once a session has concluded, the token is no
>   longer valid; your app must generate a fresh token for each session.

The text in editText changes when the user has selected a place from autocomplete predictions (the session ends, a new one will be created when the user selects a new place).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @evan,we got this...by printing logs......it recreate instance

Comment: Glad to hear! :)